# Connection not working for login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am connecting to sql database .net 4.5 and its failing I have tcpip enabled and set to port 1433 but i am still getting connection errror.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=DAVIDBUCKLEY-PC\SQLEXPRESS2012;Database=School;Trusted_Connection=True;";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        userId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]);
        roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
    switch (userId)
    {
        case -1:
            Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
            break;
        case -2:
            Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
            break;
        default:
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

            if (ticket.IsPersistent)
            {
                cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            }
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But i still getting the following error

> Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.

SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

```
If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
The proc
```

Comment: have you enabled SQL Server Browser? Also allow port 1433 through firewall.

Comment: yes and yes brower is enabeld and port 1433 thru firewall

Comment: You error message is cut off, but it would appear to be telling you all of the requirements to automatically create the database. What about these instructions are you not understanding?

Comment: its not an express database but its isntalled via managment studio ie not in my appdata directory

Comment: have you looked up on google how to format the connection string here is a previously posted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270579/cant-connect-application-with-connection-string-sqlexpress also checkout [C# connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Can you connect using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @SteveWellens yes I can fine and browse tables and data entity is connecting fine as well but for forms auth i was using a direct connection as nedded to execute a store procedure

Answer (score -1):

Having problems connecting to SQL Server?
Try disconnecting firewall. If you can connect with firewall disconnected, may be you miss some input rules like "sql service broker", add this input rules to your firewall:
"SQL ADMIN CONNECTION" TCP PORT 1434
"SQL ADMIN CONNECTION" UDP PORT 1434
"SQL ANALYSIS SERVICE" TCP PORT 2383
"SQL BROWSE ANALYSIS SERVICE" TCP PORT 2382
"SQL DEBUGGER/RPC" TCP PORT 135
"SQL SERVER" TCP PORT 1433 and others if you have dinamic ports
"SQL SERVICE BROKER" TCP PORT 4022

Greetings.
Pau.